# A quick regular expression needed

Tags: php, regex

I want a regular expression which ALLOWS only this:

```
 letter a-z
 case insensitive
 allows underscores
 allows any nrs
```

How should this be written?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing... Don't know much about regexp

Comment: Which language? All of the ones in your tags?

Comment: Ok, I'm removing the other language tags.

Comment: why would you want to put some magic incantation into your code that you hardly even understand instead of just writing a few lines of code?

Comment: I just need the regexp... I understand code Bill, just not good at regex, and your pointless question isn't helping

Comment: Bill is right though. A regex like this is fairly easy to learn how to construct, and it's highly useful to know how to do that.

Comment: I think what Bill meant was that if you don't understand magic incantations (which should be a synonym for regex) and you can get the behaviour you want with a few lines of perfectly understandable code, why do you want the unintelligible write-only way? Learning regex is another alternative.

Comment: @ceejayoz - the point of stackoverflow is to spread knowledge. People generally provide explanations for the regular expressions they provide.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions."  Now they have two problems --Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Please not that Zawinski joke AGAIN

Comment: @Jeff: And some people just can't hold it when they know a certain quote that might or might not apply.

Comment: What's up with all the downvotes? The question is clear, correctly written and has a precise answer -- all the requisites needed by SO. Is it trivial? So what.

Comment: Matt elegantly said SO is about spreading knowledge; If you have an objection to why I shouldn't ask this question then let me know. But your arguments are not valid when you say I "Should" know this. I have learnt one new thing now thanks to you and SO, which is the whole point of SO. no point in arguing here, or downvoting...

Comment: What's up with the close vote? This is a valid question.

Comment: @Matt I'm just saying the attitude of "I just need the regexp" is detrimental. I'm not downvoting, closing, or anything, just saying @Camran should heed @Bill K's suggestion of learning how the regex *works* instead of just using it.

Comment: There are plenty of valid reasons to use Regex one can be familiar with whether or not they understand the technology behind it or syntax used for it.  As for down-votes, my bet is still that there's a hidden badge for it... humanity simply isn't that chudly in the programming sector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be

```
\w
```

if I'm not mistaken (As it turns out, it depends: In PHP the [meaning of `\w`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php) changes with the [locale](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) that's currently in effect). You can use [a more explicit form](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.squarebrackets.php) to nail it down:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_]
```

I use it in context, add start-of-string and end-of-string [anchors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) and a [quantifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) that defines how many characters you will allow:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$
```

Answer (score 5):

**PHP:**

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-z0-9_]/i', $input)) {
  // invalid input
} else {
  // valid input
}
```

So `[a-z0-9_]` is a character set for your valid characters. Adding a `^` to the front (`[^a-z0-9_]`) negates it. The logic is, if any character matches something that ISN'T in the valid character set, the input is considered invalid.

The `/i` at the end makes the match case insensitive.

Comment: +1 - Some times the easier regexp to test/read is the negation.  Rather than allow only certain characters, just test for the existence of an invalid character.

Comment: But when the pattern is the same (bar negation), it's only a matter of inverting the if/else blocks, or putting a `!` before `preg_match`. Negating makes it easier when you change the problem, not when you write the same exact pattern in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 1):

How should it be written? (breaking it into multiple lines)

```
/           # Start RegExp Pattern
 ^          # Match beginning of string only
 [a-z0-9_]* # Match characters in the set [ a-z, 0-9 and _ ] * = Zero or more times
 $          # Match end of string
/i          # End Pattern - Case Insensitive Matching
```

Giving you

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_]*$/i', $input)) {
  // input is valid
}
```

You could also use a `+` instead of `*` if you want to force at least one character as well.

Comment: Isn't this case-sensitive? Your code that is (not the explanation!)

Comment: @Vivin Paliath - Yup! Thanks for the gentle nudge.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match('/^[0-9a-z_]+$/i', $string)) {
  //if it matches
}

else {
  //if it doesn't match
}
```

`[0-9a-z_]` is a character class that defines the digits 0 through 9, the letters a through z and the underscore. The `i` at the end makes the match case-insensitive. `^` and `$` are anchors that match the beginning and end of the string respectively. The `+` means 1 or more characters.

Comment: Wrong. This will return a false positive if the input happens to contain a valid character - even if it also contains invalid characters.

Comment: This wouldn't work. "a b c d" would pass, as you're only looking for one of the characters in the string to match. Modify the pattern to `/^[0-9a-z_]$/i` and it'll work.

Comment: @ceejayox That would only match one character - I added a `+` for 1 or more.